# Разместить 4 точки на двухмерной плоскости

Tags: алгоритм

Суть: Есть массив который представляет плоскость, к которому можно обратиться как

```
map[x][y]
```

Он представляет из себя набор из 0 и 1, где 0 - это ничего и 1 это точка.
x и y - Координаты.
Я хочу разместить в нём 4 точки случайным образом так, что-бы точки не были ближе 10 клеток (координат) к другим точкам. Подскажите алгоритм действий?

Comment: Дайте более развернутый ответ, так как не понятно, что должен из себя представлять ваш массив, приведите его пример.

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл. Подправил.

Comment: а как рассчитывается расстояние между точками в 10 клеток?

Comment: 1) Расстояние не менее 10 - это по любой оси или по отрезку? 2) Ограничения на значения x и y имеются? а то ить раскидать все 4 точки по бесконечностям... 3) Ограничение на расстояние от новой точки - распространяется на остальные 3 добавленные точки? 4) Какова "мера случайности" точки?

Comment: Каким образом измеряется расстояние между точками? Каков размер массива?

Comment: Главное - размер массива. А то если это 10x10 - то как-то и выбора особого не наблюдается...

Answer (score 0):

Расстояние между точками проверяем по формуле из геометрии.

1. Ставим случайную точку.
2. К координатам точки прибавляем-вычитаем 10 или больше, чтобы получить координаты следующих точек. При этом нужно не забывать о границах массива